# Resolve page break

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

[image][image]How can i resolve page breaker that occurring when redirect to rpt file .
sample,

```
AWARDS:

[large space]


settled by:Jake
```

Thanks

Comment: you'll have to give us more information. probably best would be a screenshot of the report in design mode and another of it in preview mode

Comment: I am getting a large space between Group Header section (AWARDS:) and Details "settled by:" in my exported pdf file.

Comment: have you set new page before property ?

Comment: not really, i am newbie to crystal report :)

Comment: the report preview is a start- can you add the report design view too? we can then start to ask the right questions

Comment: Some section maybe has set "Print at bottom of page" property?

Comment: Arvo , not set this property .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unchecking the textbox's "Keep Object Together" checkbox.